# I'm stuck trying to implement Visual Website Optimizer VWO with Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

I'm using Univeral Analytics and cant find any information about how i do this. If I could see what value to capture with jQuery i could set it up but i dont see it in the code.

Any help will be useful

Comment: VWO Website "No coding or HTML knowledge required!" lol

Comment: there is a one click integration for UA inside VWO. Did you try that? if you are using GTM you would have to use a setting inside GTM where you specify the custom tracker name as blank.

Comment: Yep its the one click integration, how do i make the custom tracker

Answer (score 0):

Just set the tracker name as suggested in [How to make Google Tag Manager Analytics tags use the DEFAULT tracker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634729/how-to-make-google-tag-manager-analytics-tags-use-the-default-tracker) and it will make it work if you are using UA from inside GTM.